# equivalent to setLevel for a panel in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a panel I am making in Cocoa (as opposed to a window) I want to set the panel to floating level on the screen so it will appear above everything else, but panel does not have the method setLevel like window does.

Any alternative to this?

I am not able to change the panel to a window btw!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Most methods listed in the `NSWindow` class reference also work on `NSPanel` because `NSPanel` inherits from `NSWindow`. In conclusion, simply use `setLevel:` like this:

```
[thePanel setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel];
```

The standard window levels in Mac OS X:

```
#define NSNormalWindowLevel          kCGNormalWindowLevel
#define NSFloatingWindowLevel        kCGFloatingWindowLevel
#define NSSubmenuWindowLevel         kCGTornOffMenuWindowLevel
#define NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel     kCGTornOffMenuWindowLevel
#define NSMainMenuWindowLevel        kCGMainMenuWindowLevel
#define NSStatusWindowLevel          kCGStatusWindowLevel
#define NSModalPanelWindowLevel      kCGModalPanelWindowLevel
#define NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel       kCGPopUpMenuWindowLevel
#define NSScreenSaverWindowLevel     kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel
#define NSDockWindowLevel            kCGDockWindowLevel
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The panel now seems to reside above all other windows in the same application, however when another application is in focus, the panel disappears, even if it is just over the desktop. Is there a property that makes a window or panel disappear when it's application is out of focus?

Comment: maybe this needs to be changes... previewWindow = [[MyiSightWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect 
                  styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
                 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                   defer:YES
                  screen:[[NSApp mainWindow] screen]];

Comment: `[thePanel setHidesOnDeactivate:NO];` is probably what you're looking for.